# Qt: How does QStackedWidget and QComboBox's index work?

Tags: qt

Confused by the index system of the mentioned widgets.
If I have a stacked widget, it contains 5 widgets and their index is:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

If I now remove the widget of index 2, the index of all other widgets will become:

```
0 1 3 4
```

or

```
0 1 2 3
```

?

Comment: The indexes will become 0 1 2 3

Comment: Is it the same for all other similar widgets? like tabwidget, combobox...

Comment: Yes, the same principle works for everything. If there's an index, then there's an array. And arrays always contain contiguous values.